# jQuery validation plugin error message layout

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, validation, layout, message

The problem is that validation error message for `IE 9` is jumping.

Is it possible that it appears with no affecting current layout?

It means, appears in empty space between `inputs`.

Here is simple case in jsFiddle: [jsSample](http://jsfiddle.net/wJCQw/90/)
`First Name` is validated.

Library used:
**1.** jQuery 1.7
**2.** jQuery validation plugin.

Comment: In IE10 in IE9 mode validation message slightly shifts inputs, as well as in Firefox. What problem are you referring to?

Comment: the problem of this shifting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add `height` attribute for `div` element, that is container for `input` and error message.

was:

```
.billing-address .wrap-data{
    padding-top:24px;
    position: relative;
}
```

correct style:

```
.billing-address .wrap-data{
    padding-top:24px;
    position: relative;
    height:24px;
}
```